# Usage of checked selector inside a div

Tags: html, css

As I'm not a CSS or bootstrap expert, I requested help to understand side effects of CSS 'checked' usage.

I have the following simple HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" id="check1" name="mychoice" value="bechoice1">
<label for="check1" class="side-label">Mon choix 1</label>
<br/>

<input type="radio" id="check2" name="mychoice" value="bechoice2">
<label for="check2" class="side-label">Mon choix 2</label>
<br/>

<input type="radio" id="check3" name="mychoice" value="bechoice3">
<label for="check3" class="side-label">Mon choix 3</label>
<br/>

<div class="ischoiceno1" >Content n° 1</div>
<div class="ischoiceno2" >Content n° 2</div>
<div class="ischoiceno3" >Content n°3</div>
```

I'm using it with this CSS code:

```
.ischoiceno1, .ischoiceno2, .ischoiceno3 {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 35px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:dashed ;
  border-color:#33ae74;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
#check1:checked ~ .ischoiceno1 {  display: block;}
#check2:checked ~ .ischoiceno2 {  display: block;}
#check3:checked ~ .ischoiceno3 {  display: block;}
```

And this code is running well in an old version of the website.
Rewriting the entire application, i now using bootstrap as CSS framework.

This code alone is still running.
But when I include the initial inputs in a div, this is not working.
As my target is to include those code in 'form-group' or 'row'divs obviously it will not running.

What do I have to change? I assumed it is in the CSS that I have to customize the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` selector you are using is called the [general sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)

`#check1:checked ~ .ischoiceno1 {  display: block;}` will select every element with class `.ischoiceno1` that is preceded by a checked `#check1` element.

If you put all the input elements in a container div, that logic does not work anymore (it does not work on nested elements). I can't think of a pure CSS solution. A javascript solution is the way to go here I think.

```js
$(function() {
  // watch for changes in the selection
  $("input[name='mychoice']").change(radioSelectionChanged);
});

// function that is called when selection changes
function radioSelectionChanged(){
  // hide all elements
  $('.choice').hide();
  // show only the selected one
  $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
}
```

```css
.choice {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 35px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:dashed ;
  border-color:#33ae74;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radioContainer">
  <input type="radio" id="check1" name="mychoice" value="bechoice1"> <label for="check1" class="side-label">Mon choix 1</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" id="check2" name="mychoice" value="bechoice2"> <label 
  for="check2" class="side-label">Mon choix 2</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" id="check3" name="mychoice" value="bechoice3"> <label for="check3" class="side-label">Mon choix 3</label><br/>
</div>


<div class="choice" id="bechoice1" >Content n° 1</div>
<div class="choice" id="bechoice2" >Content n° 2</div>
<div class="choice" id="bechoice3" >Content n°3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a pure CSS solution first. So I will implement a JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `~` is called sibling selector. It will try to find the siblings and apply the styles.

Your example will work because all the `div` contents are siblings to the `radio` buttons. So when move your radio buttons into another `div` then it loose the sibling.

If you want to achieve the same effect using only CSS then you have to follow the same structure means move all the code into one parent. Otherwise you can use `javascript/jquery` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for?

```css
.group {
  position: relative;
}
.ischoiceno1, .ischoiceno2, .ischoiceno3 {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:dashed ;
  border-color:#33ae74;
  font-size: 12pt;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 35px;
  right:10px;
}
#check1:checked ~ .ischoiceno1 {  display: block;}
#check2:checked ~ .ischoiceno2 {  display: block;}
#check3:checked ~ .ischoiceno3 {  display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="group">
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="check1" name="mychoice" value="bechoice1"> <label for="check1" class="side-label">Mon choix 1</label>
  <div class="ischoiceno1" >Content n° 1</div>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="check2" name="mychoice" value="bechoice2"> <label 
for="check2" class="side-label">Mon choix 2</label>
  <div class="ischoiceno2" >Content n° 2</div>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="check3" name="mychoice" value="bechoice3"> <label for="check3" class="side-label">Mon choix 3</label>
  <div class="ischoiceno3" >Content n°3</div>
</div>
 </div>
```